# What is the etymology of "split horizon" in computer networking?

Tags: etymology

In computer networking, there are two concepts which have the phrase "split horizon" in their names:

- [Split horizon route advertisement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_horizon_route_advertisement): if a device learned about a change in network topology, it will pass it to its neighbors, but not back to the one it originally came from.
- [Split-horizon DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS): when resolving domain names, the server will give different answers depending on who is asking.

What is the etymology of "split horizon" in the names of these concepts? What do they have to do with "splitting" and "horizons"?

Comment: Consider "event horizon" -- it divides two areas (inside and outside) that don't communicate with each other. I suspect this is the metaphor that was used.

Comment: @Barmar: could you please make it into a proper answer and back it up with sources (or specify that it's your own understanding of things)? Thank you.

Comment: It's just my guess, I don't have enough information to make a real answer.

Comment: @Barmar : this division in a neighboring area and a distant zone was also my feeling, by analogy with "radio horizon", but I could not identify these 2 areas in routing map update.